# How to build and run Rust code with a single Sublime Text shortcut?

Tags: rust, sublimetext3

I have installed the "Rust Enhanced" plugin onto Sublime Text 3126 and I am able to build and run a `*.rs` program opened in Sublime Text.

In reality, the process is a nightmare:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd+Shift+B</kbd>
2. Select `Rust` to compile
3. Make sure there is no errors
4. Press <kbd>Cmd+Shift+B</kbd>
5. Select `Rust - Run` to run the last executable built

<kbd>Cmd+B</kbd> just repeats the last command executed.

How can this be shortened into a single shortcut?

Answer (score 5):

I like this answer posted on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-Rust-code-inside-Sublime-Text-3), except that you don't have to do point 1 listed there. Here are the steps:

1. Go to your workspace folder or wherever you're going to create your project.
2. From the command line(Shift + Right click when inside the folder in Windows), invoke

   `cargo new PROJECT_NAME --bin`
3. This creates a main.rs file inside src folder. Open it and code away.
4. Run <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + B</kbd> once and select **Cargo - Run**. You can build (and run) with this from now on with only <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>.

Comment: The rust book talks about compiling and running with cargo: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-02-hello-world.html#compiling-and-running-are-separate-steps

Comment: Simple and clear. Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simple custom build I'm using to build and run from one shortcut:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "rustc $file",
    "selector": "source.rust",

    "variants": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Build & Run",
            "selector": "source.rust",
            "shell_cmd": "rustc $file && ./$file_base_name",
            "windows":
            {
                "shell_cmd": "rustc $file && $file_base_name.exe"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This does not use Cargo and thus is extremely limited.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm using a custom "build system" with Sublime.

The file (byzon.sublime-build, [cf](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/basics.html#file-format-of-sublime-build-files)) is placed in `c:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\` and looks like this:

```
{ "cmd": ["c:/spool/bin/sublime_build.exe", "--build=$file"],
  // New Rust
  "file_regex": "--> (?:[\\w\\\\/\\.]+[\\\\/])?([\\w\\.]+\\.rs):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
  // Old Rust
  //"file_regex": "^(?:[\\w\\./]+/)?([\\w\\.]+\\.rs):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
  "selector": "source.rust, source.php" }
```

Once the custom "build system" file is in place, I just select it from the "Tools / Build System" menu (in case it wasn't already selected by the editor) and hitting Ctrl+B invokes my own build script (which is, unsurprisingly, written in Rust).

This provided me with far better customisation than anything else could. For example, some of my projects have the build script open a couple of log files on different High Availability servers and forward their contents right into the build console, tagging each line with the hostname of the server the line originates from, so hitting Ctrl+B I get my project rebuilt and restarted on the servers and I see their logs right away as well. Other project is synchronized and built on a local Docker image. What I'm saying is having a custom build script has its advantages.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my sublime-keymap file and added a new key map:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "build", "args": { "variant": "Run" } },
```

This compiles then runs `.rs` files on selecting `alt +` b, I tend to leave the build only as the default on `ctrl + b` and select others with `ctrl + shift + b` as required.  I added this as it seems simpler than other suggestions even though this is an old thread.